# Android Volley IllegalStateException: Marker added to finished log

Tags: android-volley, android-6.0-marshmallow

**Unable to get any solution for this issue:**

Device: Lenovo A7000-a,  OS Marshmallow(6.0)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Marker added to finished log
       at com.android.volley.VolleyLog$MarkerLog.add(SourceFile:132)
       at com.android.volley.Request.finish(SourceFile:240)
       at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(SourceFile:109)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350035/volley-bug-repeating-a-request-when-verbose-logging-is-enabled-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can disable Logs.d & Logs.v using following snippets to be add in proguard. It'll be solve your crash.

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontobfuscate
-forceprocessing
-optimizationpasses 5

-keep class * extends android.app.Activity
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
}
```

Comment: Does this disable all `Logs.d` & `Logs.v` throughout the application?